# How to programmatically add custom functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying to build a rather unique google sheets addon. Google's documentation is great for adding [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), however I want my addon to programmatically add custom functions.

For instance, the following doesn't seem to be possible:

- Assume there's a `getScript()` custom function where if you do `getScript("scraper")`, this custom function will do an HTTP call and install a new function `scraper()` in your google sheet.
- Then you can do `scraper("https://www.google.com")` to get all the text from "google.com".

I know it's possible to define `scraper()` ahead of time.

Is it possible to do so live?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You have define all your custom functions ahead of time.

Comment: Ahh that's annoying. Would be nice to dynamically add to list of custom functions.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Apps Script platform have changed a lot since this question was posted back in 2014. Regarding [editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons) they can't add random [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) but they could send parameters to an external API that might include a function name and the required parameters by that function by using `UrlFetchApp`.